# How to install bpython for Python 3?

Tags: python, pip, distutils, bpython

I've been using bpython for Python 2 and now I want to use it for Python 3 as well.

However I've run into problems. The bpython documentation reads:

> bpython supports Python 3. It's as simple as running setup.py with Python 3.

When I run the setup script it creates a build folder, but I don't know what to do from there? I want to be able to type `bpython` in the Terminal and run the bpython interface for Python 3.

I originally installed bpython with pip, that worked off the bat.

Answer (score 21):

[Run `python3 setup.py install` command](https://docs.python.org/3/install/#standard-build-and-install) (without `install` it only builds); You may need to prepend the command with `sudo`: `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

BTW, you can also use `pip`: `pip3 install bpython` or `python3 -m pip install bpython`.

And if you pip-install bpython for both 2 and 3, then you can specify which version of Python to use for a given session by using either of the following two commands:

```
python2 -m bpython
python3 -m bpython
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a beginner out! I did manage to install bpython in my "python3.5/site-packages" folder. But how do I set up bpython to enable me to type "bpython" in the Terminal? There is no executable bpython script in the bpython folder that I can alias in my bash profile?

Comment: @timkl, If you installed the package using `pip`, issuing the following command will list all the files installed: `pip3 show -f bpython`. `grep` it `pip3 show -f bpython | grep bin` to list executables. Otherwise, check `bin` directories; maybe you need to adjust `PATH` environment variable if the `bin` directory in not listed in the `PATH`.

Comment: The key for me was understanding `python3 -m bpython`

Comment: @timkl  you need to create an alias for bpython, add it to your .bashrc or .bash_aliases file like this:
alias bpython='python3 -m bpython'